# Splitting a program into Procedures/Functions

Tags: vb.net, function, procedure

Here's the code I'm using. I'm trying to organize the program by splitting it up into procedures and functions. The code worked when not split up, however when I have it in this format below, the current number becomes 0. Do I need to change the UserInput to a function instead of a procedure? I need multiple values to be updated and returned to the main program, so I didn't have any idea how I could use it as a function. Thanks in advance for any help, and I apologize for my noobness, I'm still in the early stages of learning programming in general.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Call ExplanationOfGame()
    CurrentNumber = RandomNumber()
    Label2.Text = CurrentNumber
    While CurrentNumber <> 0
        Call UserInput(UserNumber, CurrentNumber, Answer)
        Call ComputerInput(ComputerNumber, CurrentNumber, Answer)
    End While
    Call DecideWinner(CurrentNumber, Answer)
End Sub

Sub UserInput(ByVal CurrentNumber As Integer, ByVal UserNumber As Integer, ByVal Answer As Integer)
    Answer = 1
    Do
        UserNumber = InputBox("Enter number to minus from the current number (1, 2 or 3). The current number is: " & CurrentNumber)
    Loop Until (CurrentNumber - UserNumber) >= 0
    CurrentNumber = CurrentNumber - UserNumber
    Label2.Text = CurrentNumber
    MsgBox("You took " & UserNumber & " away from the current number. The new current number is " & CurrentNumber)
End Sub
```

Comment: Change your `ByVal`s to `ByRef`s.

Answer (score 1):

In the UserInput function, use ByRef instead of ByVal for the parameters.  ByVal only passes in the value of the variable, so you are not actually modifying the orginal variable.

The other option is to change it into a function and only return the CurrentValue.  You seem to be passing two parameters - UserNumber and Answer - that don't need to be passed.

You could change it to:

```
Function UserInput(CurrentNumber As Integer) As Integer
    ...
End Function
```

Then call it using:

```
CurrentNumber = UserInput(CurrentNumber)
```

Comment: Okay, so would I change the sub to a function?
Something like this perhaps?:
    'Function UserInput(ByRef CurrentNumber, ByRef UserNumber, ByRef Answer)'

Comment: Nope, it can stay a sub.  You only change to a function if you want to return a single value instead of changing existing variables.

Comment: I changed the all 'ByVal' to 'ByRef' but the problem persists?

Comment: What problem are you getting?  Have you put breakpoints in the code to step through and see if the values you are expecting are getting passed around?

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite sure how to do that, the code definitely worked before I tried splitting it into subs, so I assumed that was the problem. CurrentNumber is a random number represented in Label2.text, and that works, however in the input box that appears, currentNumber is 0.  Is there a way I could send you the full code so you may be able to see my errors?

Comment: Just made an update to my answer after reading through your code a little more.  Seems you have some unnecessary things in there that could be simplified.

Comment: Thanks for the update, would I still be able to change other values in the code though? As I need the 'Answer' variable to change in number as well as the 'CurrentNumber'

Comment: Oh... you have your parameters in the wrong order.  Your sub has CurrentNumber, UserNumber, but you're calling it with UserNumber, CurrentNumber.

Comment: Ahh great, that worked! Seems like quite a stupid mistake to make :P I should remember that now, thanks a lot for your help Phillip.